# How many attacks can I make after using greenflame blade as a bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions

I am playing a dual wielding 5th Fighter/2nd Paladin/5th Sorcerer with blade mastery that has chosen the magic initiate feat (warlock: greenflame & booming blade for cantrips and Hex for 1st level spell). This allows for 3 attacks/rd with plenty of slots for divine smite but I’d still like to use greenflame blade without feeling like I’m throwing away the round. Here is my question:

If I use sorcery points to make the greenflame blade a bonus action, how many more attacks can I make that same round without using an action surge?

Comment: Hi Goblin, welcome to the site! I've made some edits to your question to make it clearer what you're asking about. Feel free to edit further or rollback the edit if necessary. Also, I recommend taking the [tour] for a useful introduction to the site.

Comment: A small change I'd recommend to this question: I think you mean "use two Sorcery Points to make the greenflame blade a bonus action". Unlike some other Metamagic options, Quickened Spell does not depend on the level of the spell. It costs 2 Sorcery Points to cast a spell with a casting time of one Action as a Bonus Action. (PHB p. 102)

Answer (score 16):

If you use *Greenflame Blade* as a bonus action, that leaves you your regular action. With that action, you can either:

- Take the Attack action, using Extra Attack to attack twice
- Use *Greenflame Blade*, attacking once as part of the spell
- Do anything else that requires an action (except cast a non-cantrip spell, since you've already cast a bonus action spell)

What you can't do is make an attack using the Two-Weapon Fighting rules, because that requires a bonus action, and you already used yours to cast *Greenflame Blade*. So, the maximum number of attacks you can make in addition to using *Greenflame Blade* as a bonus action is 2. Unless, as you mention, you use an Action Surge, which would allow you an additional 2.

Comment: The response listing three options includes "use greenflame blade, attack once as part of the spell". Does that mean that making the greenflame blade a bonus action does not include the attack? If so, are you explaining there is no benefit to making the spell a bonus action?

Comment: @Goblin No, greenflame blade always lets you make an attack as part of casting it.

Comment: According to Miniman "greenflame blade always lets you make an attack as part of casting it" ... does that mean that using 2 sorcery points to make it become a bonus action mean that an attack takes place as part of that bonus action? Thus the 2 attacks allowed a 5th level fighter as part of their regular action remains available?

Comment: @Goblin Yep, exactly.